# Google Embed API: GEO chart - show specific country

Tags: google-maps, charts, google-api, google-visualization

I'm using **Google Embed API** to show data from google analytics visually.
I was trying to display only a specific country to show users from each of its regions.

I create a "DataChart" which has a "query" and "chart" object. In the chart object, you specify a **type** of chart, and some extra options.
If I choose "GEO", then it will use the "Geocoding" api, as I've understood it.

I am not able to show the country (Sweden) with its regions however, I don't know what to specify in the chart "options" object.

```
var location = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
        query: {
            'ids': viewId,
            'start-date': '90daysAgo',
            'end-date': 'today',
            'metrics': 'ga:users',
            'sort': '-ga:users',
            'dimensions': 'ga:region',
            'max-results': 10
        },
        chart: {
            'container': 'location',
            'type': 'GEO',
            'options': {  
                region: 150,           // <-- Europe
                country: 'SE',          // <-- just guessing

            }
        }
    });
```

This shows the whole world. If I remove "country", it shows Europe, with the top part cropped away. So I haven't specified "country" in the correct way (I am only guessing since there is no info).

The only info I can find on the GEO chart is here [Visualization: GeoChart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart), but it's not specific for the Embed API.

So does anyone have a solution for this case, and is there **info** on different properties for the chart object? ( For the query object, there is [Dimensions & Metrics Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/dimensions-metrics-explorer/) )

**Update**:

The main question was solved with a below answer:

```
'options': {
       region: 'SE',
         resolution: 'provinces'
     }
```

, but the data is not displayed in the regions, so if you have any clues around that, you could perhaps mention it as a comment.
Here is part of the data response from the query (with regions):

```
"dataTable": {
        "cols": [
            {
                "id": "ga:region",
                "label": "ga:region",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "id": "ga:users",
                "label": "ga:users",
                "type": "number"
            }
        ],
        "rows": [
            {
                "c": [
                    {
                        "v": "Stockholm County"
                    },
                    {
                        "v": "15"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "c": [
                    {
                        "v": "Vastra Gotaland County"
                    },
                    {
                        "v": "6"
                    }
                ]
            },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#configuration-options) are the only configuration options for the `GeoChart` that I'm aware of...

to display only sweden...

```
var options = {
  region: 'SE'
};
```

(remove the country option)

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages':['geochart'],
  'mapsApiKey': 'AIzaSyD-9tSrke72PouQMnMX-a7eZSW0jkFMBWY'
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

function drawRegionsMap() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Country', 'Popularity'],
  ]);

    var options = {
      region: 'SE',
      resolution: 'provinces'
    };

  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know I could specify country in the "region" property. The "resolution" property was very needed too because it displays the regions. But I still have a problem - the data doesn't show despite that I get region data (ga:region) with the api results (which I could display as a table if I want). Do you have any clue regarding that?

Comment: never used analytics or the embed api. however, it seems to work similar to normal visualizations. for the geo chart, the data must be in a certain format. there are a few options, which can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#data-format) -- are you able to share a sample of the data?

Comment: I updated the question and added some data from the api response so you can see the structure..

Comment: thanks, I will try with the provided data. in the meantime, does this run in a browser,? if so, check the browser's console (F12) for errors...

Comment: data appears to be fine. the geo chart does require an api key (see example `mapsApiKey` above), unless you provide latitude / longitude coordinates  -- google charges for the ability to look up locations by name (e.g. `"Stockholm County"`) -- see the last comment in [this thread](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2292#issuecomment-254870634) for adding in analytics, though there may be an update somewhere else...